# Trigger an URL with a cron job

Tags: cron, symfony, ovh

I'm working on a Symfony 3 website and I need to call a URL of my website with a cron job.

My website is hosted on OVH where I can configure my cron job.

For now, I have setup the command : `./demo/Becowo/batch/emailNewUser.php`

emailNewUser.php content :

```
<?php

header("Location: https://demo.becowo.com/email/newusers");

?>
```

In the log I have :

> [2017-03-07 08:08:04] ## OVH ## END - 2017-03-07 08:08:04.448008 exitcode: 0
>
> [2017-03-07 09:08:03] ## OVH ## START - 2017-03-07 09:08:03.988105 executing: /usr/local/php5.6/bin/php /homez.2332/coworkinwq/./demo/Becowo/batch/emailNewUser.php

But emails are not sent.
How should I configure my cron job to execute this URL ?
Or should I call directly my controller ? How ?

Comment: it would be a far better idea, and more secure, to write a symfony command to do what you want and call that instead.

Comment: like DevDonkey , I would do the same , if your host permits you to execute the commands .

Answer (score 1):

ok, finally it works !!!

Here are the step I followed for others :

**1/ You need a controller to send emails :**

As the controller will be called via command, you need to injec some services

em : entity manager to flush data

mailer : to access swiftMailer service to send the email

templating : to access TWIG service to use template in the email body

MemberController.php

```html
<?php

namespace Becowo\MemberBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Becowo\CoreBundle\Form\Type\ContactType;
use Becowo\CoreBundle\Entity\Contact;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;

class MemberController extends Controller
{
  private $em = null;
  private $mailer = null;
  private $templating = null;
  private $appMember = null;

  public function __construct(EntityManager $em, $mailer, EngineInterface $templating, $appMember)
  {
      $this->em = $em;
      $this->mailer = $mailer;
      $this->templating = $templating;
      $this->appMember = $appMember;
  }

 

  public function sendEmailToNewUsersAction()
  {
    // To call this method, use the command declared in Becowo\CronBundle\Command\EmailNewUserCommand 
    // php bin/console app:send-email-new-users

   $members = $this->appMember->getMembersHasNotReceivedMailNewUser();
   $nbMembers = 0;
   $nbEmails = 0;
   $listEmails = "";
    
   foreach ($members as $member) {
    $nbMembers++;
    if($member->getEmail() !== null)
    {
     $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
         ->setSubject("Hello")
         ->setFrom(array('toto@xxx.com' => 'Contact Becowo'))
         ->setTo($member->getEmail())
          ->setContentType("text/html")
         ->setBody(
             $this->templating->render(
                 'CommonViews/Mail/NewMember.html.twig',
                 array('member' => $member)
             ))
          ;

        $this->mailer->send($message);
        $nbEmails++;
        $listEmails = $listEmails . "\n" . $member->getEmail() ;

        $member->setHasReceivedEmailNewUser(true);
        
     $this->em->persist($member);
    }
   }
      $this->em->flush();

   $result = " Nombre de nouveaux membres : " . $nbMembers . "\n Nombre d'emails envoyes : " . $nbEmails . "\n Liste des emails : " . $listEmails ;
    

   return $result;
  }

}
```

**2/ Call you controller as a service**

app/config/services.yml

```html
  app.member.sendEmailNewUsers :
        class: Becowo\MemberBundle\Controller\MemberController
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', '@mailer', '@templating', '@app.member']
```

**3/ Create a console command to call your controller**

Doc : http://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html

YourBundle/Command/EmailNewUserCommand.php

```html
<?php

namespace Becowo\CronBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;

class EmailNewUserCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        
        // the name of the command (the part after "php bin/console")
        $this->setName('app:send-email-new-users')
    ->setDescription('Send welcome emails to new users') 
     ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
     // outputs a message to the console followed by a "\n"
        $output->writeln('Debut de la commande d\'envoi d\'emails');

      // access the container using getContainer()
        $memberService = $this->getContainer()->get('app.member.sendEmailNewUsers');
        $results = $memberService->sendEmailToNewUsersAction();

        $output->writeln($results);
    }
}
```

**4/ Test your command !**

In the console, call you command : `php bin/console app:send-email-new-users`

**5/ Create a script to run the command**

Doc (french) : http://www.christophe-meneses.fr/article/deployer-son-projet-symfony-sur-un-hebergement-perso-ovh

..Web/Batch/EmailNewUsers.sh

```html
#!/bin/bash

today=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H")
/usr/local/php5.6/bin/php /homez.1111/coworkinwq/./demo/toto/bin/console app:send-email-new-users --env=demo > /homez.1111/coworkinwq/./demo/toto/var/logs/Cron/emailNewUsers-$today.txt
```

Here it took me some time to get the correct script.

Take care of php5.6 : it has to match your PHP version on OVH

Don't forget to upload bin/console file on the server

homez.xxxx/name has to match with your config (I found mine on OVH, and then in the logs)

IMPORTANT : when you upload the file on the server, add execute right (CHMOD 704)

**6/ Create the cron job in OVH**

Call your script with the command : `./demo/Becowo/web/Batch/EmailNewUsers.sh`

Language : other

**7/ Wait !**

You need to wait for the next run. Then have a look on OVH cron logs, or on your own logs created via the command in the .sh file

It took me several days to get it..
Enjoy !!

Comment: Obviously the problem has been solved now so what is the next step regarding to this post?

Answer (score 0):

As commented above, you should do it with a symfony commaad. This is an example for you.

**NOTE**: Although it is working, you can always improve this example. Especially the way command calls your endpoint.

**Controller service definition:**

```
services:
    yow_application.controller.default:
        class: yow\ApplicationBundle\Controller\DefaultController
```

**Controller itself**

```
namespace yow\ApplicationBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

/**
 * @Route("", service="yow_application.controller.default")
 */
class DefaultController
{
    /**
     * @Method({"GET"})
     * @Route("/plain", name="plain_response")
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function plainResponseAction()
    {
        return new Response('This is a plain response!');
    }
}
```

**Command service definition**

```
services:
    yow_application.command.email_users:
        class: yow\ApplicationBundle\Command\EmailUsersCommand
        arguments:
            - '@http_kernel'
        tags:
            - { name: console.command }
```

**Command itself**

```
namespace yow\ApplicationBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

class EmailUsersCommand extends Command
{
    private $httpKernel;

    public function __construct(HttpKernelInterface $httpKernel)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->httpKernel = $httpKernel;
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('email:users')->setDescription('Emails users');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $request = new Request();
        $attributes = [
            '_controller' => 'yow_application.controller.default:plainResponseAction',
            'request' => $request
        ];
        $subRequest = $request->duplicate([], null, $attributes);

        $response = $this->httpKernel->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);

        $output->writeln($response);
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
$ php bin/console email:users
Cache-Control:      no-cache, private
X-Debug-Token:      99d025
X-Debug-Token-Link: /_profiler/99d025

This is a plain response!
1.0
200
OK
```

Comment: Hi ! thanks for your answer. Do you mean I can call the command 'php bin/console email:users' with the cron task ?

Comment: Something like `*/5 * * * *     cd /path/to/your/app && php bin/console --env=prod email:users` should do. I presume you know what `--env` flag means.

Comment: the thing is that to run the cron job I have to do it via OVH, where I can only call a PHP file. So I create a file containing
 <?php
exec("php bin/console app:send-email-new-users");
?>
I'll tell you if it's working