# Crontab with my Controller on Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, cron

I tried to make a cron on my Symfony 3 project.

I have make function on my controller for save data from XML file and when I what to call it on the console I have an error and I don't understand this.

It's my first Symfony project and I dont know what is wrong on my code.

I've look [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643974/trigger-an-url-with-a-cron-job) but I can't solve my probleme

This is error from console when I run php bin/console app:save-xml-data

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /data/www/weatherperf/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php on line 412

PHP   9. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller->get() /data/www/weatherperf/src/Core/LayoutBundle/Controller/LayoutController.php:125
[2017-10-11 13:14:38] php.CRITICAL: Fatal Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 0): Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object at /data/www/weatherperf/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php:412)"}


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object
```

My Controller

```
<?php

class LayoutController extends Controller
{
    private $sNameController = "CoreLayoutBundleLayout";
    private $em = null;

    public function __construct( EntityManager $em )
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/xml_uploadData", name="core_layout_xml_upload")
     */
    public function setXmlData()
    {
        $sTimestamp = date(time());

        $this->get('admin_layout.log')->addLogTo( "getData", "Début Traitement", "SaveData", $this->sNameController );
        //....

    }



}
```

My services.yml for the bundle

```
services:
    core_layout.setxmldata:
        class: Core\LayoutBundle\Controller\LayoutController
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

My commande

```
<?php

namespace Core\LayoutBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;

class SetXmlDataCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {

        // the name of the command (the part after "php bin/console")
        $this->setName('app:save-xml-data')
             ->setDescription('Save data from XML file') 
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        // outputs a message to the console followed by a "\n"
        $output->writeln('Debut de la commande de sauvegarde');

        // access the container using getContainer()
        $saveService = $this->getContainer()->get('core_layout.setxmldata');
        $results = $saveService->setXmlData();

        $output->writeln($results);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about [Minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?

Comment: @svgrafov: I've edit the post maybe it's better

Comment: Have you actually read the link I provided? You should try to reduce amount of code in your example. And your guesses don't help at all.

Comment: @svgrafov: Yes I've read it and I thought that enought but I guess no. I change my post again but maybe now it's too short ...

Comment: You should not just cut out everything. Instead, try to reduce complexity untill error disappears. Than add the smallest result, that has your error.

Comment: @svgrafov: I've comment the line who use my service and the console command works but I need to find a way to use my service when I execute my command. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you explain why you are using a 'Controller' here ? Why you dont do all the work in your Command class ?

Otherwise create a service inject the entity manager and container ('@service_container') there and do you work.

Comment: I use my Controller because I want to execute this on web too. So I have to make my function a service ?

Comment: yes I would create a service which you can call from your controller ($this->container->get('service')) and your command (with $this->getApplication()->getKernel()->getContainer()->get('service')) and do the all the work there.

Comment: Thx for your advice. I've changed my controller and make a service and now everything work !